# The number of repeated values ​in the array ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

There is a table as shown below.

[image]

How to count the number of repeated 1 and output to an array.
As a result, it should look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] AS arr,
    arrayFilter(z -> (z != 0), arrayMap(j -> length(arrayFilter(m -> (m = 1), j)), arraySplit(i -> (i = 0), arr))) AS r

┌─arr─────────────────────┬─r───────┐
│ [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1] │ [3,4,1] │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┘
```